# Synergy setup with 3 monitors and 2 computers

Tags: windows, macos, multiple-monitors, software-rec, synergy

I have 2 computers:

1. windows - server, 1 monitor
2. MacBook Pro - client, 2 monitors, arrangement: [mac] [monitor]

And I want to get something like this:

[mac] [server] [monitor] (this is my physical setup)

While MacBook-monitor setup is not changed.

I got something close to my goal but i had to change an arrangement to: [monitor] [mac]

Is there anyway to make it working? Or is there any similar software to synergy which will allow me to do such thing?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set up a synergy.sgc configuration file and point to from the Synergy dialogue - 'Use existing configuration option'. Do a search for file examples. This is not as easy as 'Configure interactively' but is worth the work. Its stable and once written transfers to latest version(s). Multiple monitors on each PC are seen as one PC by Synergy. Arrange the monitors on the relevant PCs and arrange the PC layout in Synergy. I have 3 PCs with multiple monitors set up with one PC over 2 PCs side by side. Works a treat across all monitors!

Answer (score 0):

This is my configuration, and I achieved exactly what you are looking for.  I renamed the links/screens to match your monitors:

```
    section: screens
    mac:
        halfDuplexCapsLock = false
        halfDuplexNumLock = false
        halfDuplexScrollLock = false
        xtestIsXineramaUnaware = false
        switchCorners = none 
        switchCornerSize = 0
    server:
        halfDuplexCapsLock = false
        halfDuplexNumLock = false
        halfDuplexScrollLock = false
        xtestIsXineramaUnaware = false
        switchCorners = none 
        switchCornerSize = 0

end

section: aliases
end

section: links
    mac:
        left = server
        right = server
    server:
        right = mac
        left = mac
end

section: options
    heartbeat = 5000
    relativeMouseMoves = false
    screenSaverSync = false
    win32KeepForeground = false
    disableLockToScreen = true
    clipboardSharing = true
    clipboardSharingSize = 3072
    switchCorners = none 
    switchCornerSize = 0
end
```